# Enable PCNTL on Docker PHP 8.2 image

Tags: php, docker

Trying to install the [PHP PCNTL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) onto the PHP 8.2.4-cli Docker image to utilise SIGTERM.

But it doesn't appear to enable support for it.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2.4-cli

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl
```

Testing

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .

docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash image_id

php -i | grep pcntl
```

According to online documents should expect to see `pcntl support => enabled` but doesn't appear to be enabled.

Any indicators on where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Add **RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl** into docker file.

Comment: I'm sure I tried this! Fridays heh. Thanks so much works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

```html
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl \
  && docker-php-ext-install pcntl;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).